# What is the purpose of this pins?

Tags: laptop

I have an asus fx505dy and on my motherboard there are these copper conectors(see photo) and i was wondering if it is posible to connect something like a usb 3.0 , or if somebody knows what purpose they have because i would like to use them.[image]

Comment: Unlikely to be USB 3 as it commonly uses only 9 pins/10wires. May be test pads, or perhaps a 20 pin Jtag connector for a feature not implemented on that model board. (P.s. I strongly suggest avoiding soldering on motherboards unless one is Highly experienced with soldering, surface mount devices, and has the correct equipment.)